# Add a permanent placeholder in UITextField

Tags: uitextfield

How would I modify my text field to always have an @ sign before whatever they type into it.

[textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", [textField text]];

But where do I put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your controller as delegate of the textField, then implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method

> Tells the delegate that editing stopped for the specified text field.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:

example :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", [textField text]];
}
```

Comment: Why at the end of editing though? I want the @ there from the time the UITextView appears.

Comment: Like when you add a Twitter account in iOS settings exactly.

Comment: And the user shouldn't be able to delete it either.

Comment: Then you can simply do the same with textFieldDidBeginEditing:

Comment: How to prevent from being deleted?